# an extension that runs only on those tabs where it is activated

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

HI,
I am trying to create a firefox extension that can be activated and display the UI on the click of a button. I want this extension to run only on those tabs where it is activated.
Also I want the working of the extension in one tab seperated from the working of the extension in other tab.
Any pointers as to what approach should i take, Where i can see some example(please dnt refer me to Firebug..I have tried to go through it,the code is very vast for me to make sense in the time that i have got to make this extension)..would be highly appreciated.
ThanKs a lot in advance.

Comment: I am still stuck, but will identifying the browser and then activating the extension for that browser work?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a cookie to store the tab and the status of the extension.